# How to make GUI using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So I recently started learning object-oriented programming, did most basic stuff in Java and now I want to change from console writing to actual GUI.

But I have problem understanding how it works, I read everything in oracle documentation but their examples are not so clear and easy to understand, also googled it but couldn't manage to find any good explanation. This is my last resort.

Here is my idea of how my program GUI should look: 
![like this][1]

I couldn't draw very nice but all check boxes should be aligned.

If someone can provide me explanation with code that would be great, if not just some good explanation would help me a lot, my problem is that when I align 1 thing other gets messed up.

My current code:

```
public class Zadatak2 extends JFrame{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here


        new Zadatak2();

    }


    public Zadatak2(){

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        setSize(500, 250);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        add(panel1);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);




        BorderLayout border1 = new BorderLayout();
        panel1.setLayout(border1);


        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        GridLayout grid1 = new GridLayout(3,2);

        panel2.setLayout(grid1);
        panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Bold"));
        panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Italic"));
        panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Underline"));


        panel1.add(panel2,BorderLayout.WEST);



        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
        GridLayout grid2 = new GridLayout(4,1);
        panel3.setLayout(grid2);
        panel3.add(new JCheckBox("Strikerthrough"));
        panel3.add(new JCheckBox("Teletype"));
        panel3.add(new JCheckBox("Emphasis"));
        panel3.add(new JCheckBox("Strong"));
        panel1.add(panel3,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
        BorderLayout border2 = new BorderLayout();
        panel4.setLayout(border2);

        panel4.add(new JButton("Apply"), BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 10, 70));
        panel1.add(panel4,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();
        GridLayout grid3 = new GridLayout(2,1);
        panel5.setLayout(grid3);
        panel5.add(new JLabel("Sample text"));
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea("Sample text");
        panel5.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 0, 10, 30));
        ta.setSize(200, 200);
        panel5.add(ta);
        panel1.add(panel5,BorderLayout.EAST);


        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Thanks for help from everyone, finally made the gui right, now I understand thins much better.

Comment: OK added code and image of how it looks now, so as you guys can see i need help aligning checkboxes and aligning that text area

Comment: Alignment is the least of your problems.  I'd figure out how to make the rest of it work with the back end.

Comment: I want to learn how to use Swing first, then i will do logic, I want to know how to make it work because for next project I plan to make chess game which would require good formatting.

Comment: you should try and learn JavaFX which replaces java swing. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm

Comment: You are using swing in a way that introduces bugs, because you haven't learned about the Event Processing Thread, and you are updating the GUI elements on the application thread.  Please do take time to read the Swing Trail. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ Unlike others, I wouldn't ditch Swing for JavaFX (I've used both).  Such advice is akin to "fixing" a product X issue by suggesting product Y.  In short, you'll have new problems in product Y and be even further behind in your progress to getting the whole job done.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I would still recommend JavaFX because of its property binding and the option to use fxml which helps separating the UI code. Other than that, I agree.

Comment: @ModusTollens And while those are useful features, there are many scenarios were those features are not the primary point of the application (unneeded facilities), or the binding prevents a desired integration.  It's like arguing about automatic transmissions or manual ones.  They're both the best fit, depending on the driver's needs and capabilities.  Once you get too deep into the "switch to X" game, it's just persuasion without problem solving.  After all, they could do this in Tcl/TK, Qt, Motif, Xlib, gtk/glib, or fltk.  None of those have the same problems as Swing (or JavaFX)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To position the check boxes in the `GridLayout`, you should not define a panel for each column. Just define and place them like this:

```
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
GridLayout grid1 = new GridLayout(4, 2);

panel2.setLayout(grid1);
panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Bold"));
panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Strikerthrough"));
panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Italic"));
panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Teletype"));
panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Underline"));
panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Emphasis"));
panel2.add(new JLabel(""));  // fill the empty cell with an empty label
panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Strong"));
```

---

However, since you have a `TextArea` that should be aligned with the check boxes and span several rows, I would recomment using a `GridBagLayout` instead. It's more code to write, but much more flexible than the `GridLayout`.

An example:

```
 public Zadatak2() {

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    setSize(500, 250);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    add(panel1);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    BorderLayout border1 = new BorderLayout();
    panel1.setLayout(border1);

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    GridBagLayout grid1 = new GridBagLayout();

    panel2.setLayout(grid1);
    panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

    Insets insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = insets;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Bold"), c);

    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = insets;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Strikerthrough"), c);

    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.insets = insets;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Italic"), c);

    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.insets = insets;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Teletype"), c);

    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.insets = insets;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Underline"), c);

    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.insets = insets;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Emphasis"), c);

    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 3;
    c.insets = insets;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    panel2.add(new JCheckBox("Strong"), c);

    insets = new Insets(2, 40, 2, 2);
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = insets;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    panel2.add(new JLabel("Sample text"), c);

    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.insets = insets;
    c.weightx = .5;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.gridheight = 3;
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea("Sample text", 4, 4);
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta);
    panel2.add(sp, c);

    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 5;
    c.insets = new Insets(40, 40, 2,2);
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    panel2.add(new JButton("Apply"), c);


    panel1.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pack();

    setVisible(true);
}
```

The result:

[image: Screenshot of UI using GridBagLayout]

Please see the `GridBagLayout` [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) and the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) to learn about all the options of this layout.

Comment: I have to admit that my Java Swing is a bit rusty, I use JavaFX by now (and I recommend using JavaFX if you have the choice).

Comment: Looks good to me, 1+, but be sure to set the JTextArea's row and column properties (a constructor can do this for you), and placing it in a JScrollPane. Also, `pack()` should be called on the JFrame after filling it with components and before setting it visible.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Good point. Added the JScrollPane and packed, thanks!

Comment: Huge thanks for help, I got confused at first with that GridBagLayout because there is lack of good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to nest JPanels each using its own layout. For instance your imaged GUI could be made one of many ways. The overall JPanel could use BoxLayout oriented to the line, and on the left have a GridLayout using JPanel on the right a BorderLayout using JPanel. For example:

[image]

Other issues:

- The JTextArea should be placed into a JScrollPane, and the scrollpane then added to the GUI.
- **NEVER** set the sizes or preferred sizes of text components, especially JTextAreas as that will prevent them from working correctly, especially if within a scrollpane.
- Instead set the JTextArea's column and row properties.
- Avoid setting sizes in general. Let the GUI components and layouts set their own sizes by calling `pack()` on the JFrame after adding everything and before setting it visible.

For example, with slight modification:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleGui extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] CHK_BOX_TEXTS = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
            "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    private String title = "My Title";
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
    private JButton applyButton = new JButton("Apply");

    public SimpleGui() {
        // gridlayout with 2 columns, variable rows
        JPanel checkBoxPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 4, 4));
        for (String chkBoxText : CHK_BOX_TEXTS) {
            checkBoxPanel.add(new JCheckBox(chkBoxText));
        }
        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        leftPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
        leftPanel.add(checkBoxPanel);
        leftPanel.add(Box.createGlue());        

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(title, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        titleLabel.setFont(titleLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 20));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(applyButton);

        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        rightPanel.add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        rightPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        rightPanel.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);        

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        add(leftPanel);
        add(rightPanel);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleGui");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new SimpleGui());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Which displays as:

[image]

Comment: @ModusTollens: thanks for the 1+ but I created this as a community wiki, meaning rep doesn't count (in case you're not familiar with community wiki concept) and anyone can edit and improve it.

Comment: ... and someone down-voted it (?) which again doesn't count, but is weird, since it's considered a community answer. Go figure.

Comment: Thanks for the help, would choose you for correct answer as well but i can only choose 1, and that guy was first, anyway huge thanks

Comment: @Niki: his answer is good, so select it. Again, no one gets rep points for this question, good or bad, since it's a community wiki.